# Picasso not loading images with Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, picasso, dagger-2

I'm still learning Dagger 2 and tried to create a simple app using it. I am having trouble making Picasso work since I can't see any errors in the logs. Here's my code

#### AppModule.java

```
@Module(includes = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, NetworkModule.class, ViewModelModule.class})
public class AppModule {
    ...

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    Picasso picasso(App app, OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader) {
        return new Picasso.Builder(app.getApplicationContext())
                .downloader(okHttp3Downloader)
                .loggingEnabled(true)
                .build();
    }
    ...
}
```

#### NetworkModule.java

This is where the OkHttp3Downloader dependency is located.

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Timber.i(message));
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    public File file(App app) {
        return new File(app.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "okhttp_cache");
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    Cache cache(File file) {
        return new Cache(file, 10 * 1000 * 1000);
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor, Cache cache) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient);
    }
 }
```

#### AppComponent.java

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, BuildersModule.class})
public interface AppComponent{

    void inject(App app);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(App application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

#### App.java

This is my App.java class where I initialized Dagger.

```
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

And in my activity I made use of field injection `@Inject MoviesAdapter adapter;` and made use of constructor injection in my adapter

```
@Inject
public MoviesAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
    this.picasso = picasso;
}
```

I then called `picasso.load(...)` method. But no images are being loaded on the ImageViews of my RecyclerView. Attached below is the Picasso log and it doesn't say any error. What might be the problem? Is there something wrong on how I initialized Picasso using Dagger? Your help is very much appreciated.

```
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R230] Request{https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//8bcpki9GfXdXj9esFpPtlate8v0.jpg}
D/Picasso: Hunter      removed      [R222]+466ms from 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R230]+4ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R230]+5ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R231] Request{https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//4nKoB6wMVXfsYgRZK5lHZ5VMQ6J.jpg}
D/Picasso: Hunter      removed      [R223]+635ms from 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R231]+5ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R231]+13ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R232] Request{https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//5LYSsOPzuP13201qSzMjNxi8FxN.jpg}
D/Picasso: Hunter      removed      [R224]+706ms from 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R232]+3ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R232]+4ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R233] Request{https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//2lIr27lBdxCpzYDl6WUHzzD6l6H.jpg}
D/Picasso: Hunter      removed      [R226]+637ms from 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R233]+2ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R233]+4ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R234] Request{https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//tCBxnZwLiY1BOKw3tH6AxHZdqPh.jpg}
D/Picasso: Hunter      removed      [R225]+736ms from 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R234]+4ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R234]+3ms
```

---

### Edit

On `onBindViewHolder()` I called `picasso.load()`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MoviesHolder holder, int position) {  
    picasso.load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movieList.get(position).getPosterPath()).into(holder.ivMovie);
}
```

---

Comment: Post the code where you called `picasso.load(...)`.

Comment: Hello @LeoAso, I added it already. Using `Picasso.get().load(...)` would load the images though, so I'm sure the URL is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. There was a problem regarding OkHttp3Downloader since when I remove it, picasso can successfully load images. Then I tried importing com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader rather than com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader and it works now. I don't really know why I can't use jakewharton's though and what's the difference between the two.

Comment: I ran into the same issue that you were facing today and your answer helped me. The weird part with this issue was, that my app worked fine while using "com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader" before and I had changed back to your solution. Still confused !!